# django manage.py can not find command

Tags: django

[image: My folders]

When I run
python manage.py loadcsv --csv reviews/management/commands/WebDevWithDjangoData.csv

manage.py cannot find command loadcsv.
Any help

Comment: It should be `commands`, not `command`

Comment: Not sure if this could be the case, but `management` directory is missing a `__init__.py` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please rename folder **command** to **commands** and try again.

Comment: Sorry for this dumb question and thanks a lot for your answer. It was my mistake.